# How to allow underscore and dash with ctype_alnum()?

Tags: php, regex

How can I add the exception of `_` and `-` as valid characters when using [ctype_alnum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) ?

#### I have the following code:

```
if ( ctype_alnum ($username) ) {

  return TRUE;

} elseif (!ctype_alnum  ($username)) {
    
  $this->form_validation->set_message(
    '_check_username',
    'Invalid username! Alphanumerics only.'
  );

  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Since ctype_alnum only validates alpha numeric character, 
Try this:

```
$sUser = 'my_username01';
$aValid = array('-', '_');

if(!ctype_alnum(str_replace($aValid, '', $sUser))) {
    echo 'Your username is not properly formatted.';
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry @minitech I do not have 8K reputation to understand this

Comment: @minitech it means for me a str_replace is easier to understand than a preg_match

Comment: This answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Use `preg_match` instead, maybe?

```
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+$/", $username)) {
    return true;
} else {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_username', 'Invalid username! Alphanumerics only.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to use ctype_alnum AND have exceptions, in this case I also allow hyphens ( OR statement).

```
$oldString = $input_code;
$newString = '';
$strLen = mb_strlen($oldString);
for ($x = 0; $x < $strLen; $x++) 
   {
     $singleChar = mb_substr($oldString, $x, 1);
     if (ctype_alnum($singleChar) OR ($singleChar == '-'))
        {
          $newString = $newString . $singleChar;
        }
   }
$input_code = strtoupper($newString);
```

Comment: This solution seems to go out of its way to be super inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The regex equivalent is very brief and easy to read.

`~^[\w-]+$~` This pattern requires the whole string to be comprised of one or more letters, numbers, underscores, or hyphens.

Regex allows you to skip the data preparation step and directly access the evaluation -- resulting in cleaner, leaner, more direct, professional-looking code.

```
if (preg_match('~^[\w-]+$~', $username)) {
    return true;
} else {
    $this->form_validation->set_message(
        '_check_username',
        'Invalid username! Alphanumerics, underscores, and hyphens only.'
    );
    return false;
}
```